# Are there more ON UPDATE's in mySql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello I know this function on create tables witch is very common:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (   
             user_lastvisit datetime NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    ...
```

the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP will be "updated" ON UPDATE

Are there other possibilitys to update? Like increment the field.

```
user_visits int(8) NOT NULL default 0 ON UPDATE user_visits+1
```

Can't find any docs.

Comment: If you want to update some values you can check if triggers fits you!

Answer (score 1):

Use mysql triggers.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html

After you create the table run this query once it will increment the user_visits field every time you update a row.

```
CREATE TRIGGER increment_visits before update ON users
   FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.user_visits = NEW.user_visits +1;
```